# vc++ sscanf assign %f to double doesn't work

Tags: visual-c++

where do i do wrong here?

```
char *cmt,*dump;
   double value=0;
   if (cmt = strstr(fulldesc, "(TR="))
   {
       sscanf(cmt, "%s=%f)",dump, &value);
```

the fulldesc is like "(TR=100.5)" or "(TR=1000)"
i already tried changing the double to float
but the value when i print it later is always 0 or system crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scanning `cmt` with `%s` format specifier into uninitialized pointer `dump`. Crash is the BEST thing you can get.

ADDED:

Well, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx), when `sscanf()` processes `%s`, it reads:

> String, up to first white-space character (space, tab or newline)

You have no spaces in the input, so entire string `"(TR=100.5)"` is assigned to `dump`.

But **WHY** do you need that `dump` anyway, since you **KNOW** what the characters are? Just use:

```
sscanf(cmt, "(TR=%f)", &value);
```

Comment: thanks Vlad, i change the *dump to dump[32] and it doesn't crash anymore, but still can't get the double value

Comment: to prepare the code in case there will be future additional to cmt before or after (TR=%lf)

Answer (score 0):

i use %lf to scan to double
and yes as Vlad said the %s reads the whole string so the %lf doesn't get the value